# How to print from class with no print lines in class

Tags: class

I am trying to print by making it a string in the class. I am trying not to have any print lines in the class at all. I can't figure out how to not have the print lines in my **printBoard** method.

```
class MakeString() {

fun printThis(): String {
    var line = arrayOf("hello","printMe") 
    var addThis = "there"

       for (element in array) {
            println()
       }
      
       return line.toString()
   }
   
   override fun toString(): String {
       return """
           ${printThis()}
       """.trimIndent()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/) to build the output string:

```kotlin
class Puzzle(var rows :Int,var cols: Int) {
    fun printBoard(): String {
        var emptyCell = '.'
        var board = Array(rows) { Array(cols) { emptyCell } }
        val builder = StringBuilder()

        for (row in 0 until board.size) {
            for (col in 0 until board[row].size) {
                builder.append(board[row][col])
            }
            builder.append('\n')
        }
        return builder.toString()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return """
           ${printBoard()}
        """.trimIndent()
    }   
}

fun main () {
    var wordss = Puzzle(45, 45)
    println(wordss.printBoard())
}
```